# Netlify : This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

Tags: reactjs, proxy, backend, netlify

I have an ESP32 server (BACKEND with http), then I try to fetch my endpoints with fetch, everything works. now when I start hosting my website on netlify, the operation on endpoints does not want to work, I get an error: **SetCustomColor.js:7 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://smart-lamp.netlify.app/custom-color' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://192.168.118.41/custom-color?r=115&g=122&b=255'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.,**  I read that the _redirect file in the public structure is the answer to my problem, but it doesn't work properly, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? code:

**_redirect**:

```
/h/* http://192.168.118.41/section-color/fire 200!
```

**FetcherReact**:

```
 const apiUrl = `https://smart-lamp.netlify.app/h`;
 await fetch(apiUrl);
```